# How to connect Windows Live Messenger via XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, windows-live-messenger

(Not so) Recently, Microsoft announced that Windows Live Messenger (formerly MSN Messenger) is now available via XMPP protocol. I thought then I could be able to connect using any messenger client with XMPP/Jabber protocol, however this doesn't seem to be so simple.
According o Microsoft, I need to connect to xmpp.messenger.live.com on port 5222 with SSL.
How can I connect using such protocol, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft is using a custom SASL mechanism for the OAuth authentication. You can only connect with software which implements this SASL mechanism. AFAIK none of the popular XMPP clients implements it. And Microsoft did not implement any of the mandatory SASL mechanisms of teh XMPP RFCs to their XMPP server.